# Looking for a vertical NSToolBar lookalike

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm looking for an NSToolBar type of object to use in my application. I need it to be vertical and to look nice. The buttons on the object do not need to be repositioned or customizable like the NSToolBar it, but I would like the same look and feel the NSToolBar has, just vertical.

I've tried the google route, but I'm not really sure what to search for when it comes to looking for obj-c objects or examples.

I know seeing as what I want is basically a static set of buttons along the side of my window I could just use a bunch of buttons, but it doesn't have the nice seamless look that the NSToolBar does.

Is there something out there similar to what I'm looking for? Is there a repository of obj-c objects or a nice collection of them on a site that I'm just not finding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wouldn't have much in the way of functionality, but if you check the 'Textured' box (under 'Appearance') in Interface Builder of an NSWindow, it will make the whole window look like a toolbar.  Dropping a well-placed NSBox (set to 'Custom', and with a fill color of the background of a window-or-so) on top of the window leaving only a strip for what would look like a toolbar, you would have a visual approximation, although without any functionality of an NSToolbar whatsoever.  Buttons would all have to be done manually, etc, etc.

However, I must caution you that this sounds like a major violation of the HIG.  If you are trying to make something twitterish, I won't dissuade you, but it is a sort of crosroads there's no need to cross until Apple decides which path it is going to take.

Answer (score 0):

The toolbar itself wouldn't be too tricky, but if you wanted to allow customization, that would be tricky.  Since you didn't mention customization (or showing/hiding) all you really want is a vertical bar of buttons and a background color that matches the window color.

Make your window a textured window, using `NSTexturedWindowMask`, then create a subclass of `NSView` with the dimensions you want, drawing its background to match the window background color.

```
-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
  [[[self window] backgroundColor] set];
  NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
}
```

The buttons will just be subviews of this view.

Like I say, customization and showing/hiding make this is much harder task to achieve.